# Guardar multiples imagenes en firebase storage

Tags: firebase, storage

en una app que estoy desarrollando tengo el siguiente "Problema". Cuando cargo una imagen al storage de firebase esta se guarda solo con un nombre (Incidente1) lo cual implica que cuando intento cargar alguna otra esta sobreescribe la anterior no dejandome alojar multiples imagenes. he jugado con el filepath dejando nada despues del "" pero no he podido conseguir lo que quiero que es alojar multiples imagenes.

```
private fun uploadFile() {


    if(filepath!=null){
        var pd = ProgressDialog(this)
        pd.setTitle("Cargando Imagen")
        pd.show()

        var imageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("Incidentes/Incidente1")
        imageRef.putFile(filepath)
                .addOnSuccessListener {p0 ->
                    pd.dismiss()
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Imagen Subida", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                }

                .addOnFailureListener {p0 ->
                    pd.dismiss()
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,p0.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                }
                .addOnProgressListener {p0 ->
                    var progress = (100.0 * p0.bytesTransferred) / p0.totalByteCount
                    pd.setMessage("Cargado ${progress.toInt()}%")

                }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema está en la siguiente línea de tu código:

```
var imageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("Incidentes/Incidente1")
```

La función `Child(string pathString)` devuelve una instancia de `StorageReference` que apunta al destino donde será guardado el archivo y eso incluye el nombre que tendrá.

Como el string que le pasas termina en `Incidente1` esa parte de la cadena es considerada el nombre del archivo.

Para resolverlo concatena el nombre con el que debería guardarse el archivo. Por ejemplo:

```
var imageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("Incidentes/" + nombreDelArchivo)
```

Comment: Según entiendo además debo crear una variable con el "nombreDelArchivo"?

Comment: Efectivamente, lo escribí así como un ejemplo pero debes generar el nombre de alguna forma.